# Swift - How changing textView height dynamically in constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to change a text views's height in the middle of the table view cell by context. After textView I have another views, constant height provided by auto layout constraints.

Actually I will get first 150 characters from context to show, but I think using auto resize needed to prevent another screen sizes problem.

How Can I use auto dimension, Is there any way to assign table view row height like this?

```
let height = 4 + 17 + contextHeight + 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the storyboard, add an aspect ratio for the `textview`, Then check "`Remove at build time`" option.

In `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let contentSize = self.TextViewTitle.sizeThatFits(self.TextViewTitle.bounds.size)
    var frame = self.TextViewTitle.frame
    frame.size.height = contentSize.height
    self.TextViewTitle.frame = frame

    aspectRatioTextViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.TextViewTitle, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.TextViewTitle, attribute: .Width, multiplier: TextViewTitle.bounds.height/TextViewTitle.bounds.width, constant: 1)
    self.TextViewTitle.addConstraint(aspectRatioTextViewConstraint!)

}
```